# ngfor of manytomany class union in angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

In my Angular project, I want to associate many elements of `CodeB` with many `CodeA`. I tried to associate them in this way through `association` classes which I will then need to manage other parameters. I don't understand why no data entered is associated with the second select (I did some tests with data)

This is the code:

- **summary.ts**

```js
association: AssociationA[] = []
    arr: number = 0
```

- **summary.html**

```html
<div *ngFor="let el of association" [(ngModel)]="arr" name="fieldName" ngDefaultControl>
    INTERV: {{el.interv.code}}
</div>

<select class="form-control">
    <option *ngFor="let int of association[arr].associationB">
        {{int.interv.code}}
    </option>
</select>
```

- **class**

```js
export class AssociationA {
    id: number
    interv: CodeA
    associationB: AssociationB
    }
    
    export class AssociationB {
    id: number
    interv: CodeB
    }
    
    export class CodeA {
    id: number
    code: string
    }
    
    export class CodeB {
    id: number
    code: string
    }
```

- **expected output**

```html
INTERV: A3
     ------------------------
    | select               ^ | 
     ------------------------
    | a2, price: 56          |
     ------------------------
```

Comment: What are the contents of `association` ?

Comment: @Nicholas i've made an example here --> [LINK](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmavig?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: What exactly is the expected output here? Could you include an example of the output in your question also.

Comment: @NicholasK i've edited the post with expected output

Comment: @NicholasK That is, it must happen that several interventions in 'lower case' (ex: a1) are associated with one in 'upper case' (ex: A1)